# If $X_n\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}$ Show that $\frac{1}{n}S_n\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For any sequence of r.v.´s $\{X_n\}$,

If $X_n\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}$  Show that $\frac{1}{n}S_n\to 0\mbox{ a.e.}$

where $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$

thank you for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can you specify what is exactly $X_n$ and in what space is this considered?

Comment: ok, exactly (exercise 1 Pg 119: K.L chung "a Course in probability theory" 3 ed.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: Isn't this the Law of Large Numbers?  There are proofs all over the Internet.

Comment: @avs "Isn't this the Law of Large Numbers?" No it isn't. Actually the result has no probability in it (as Byron's comment shows)...

Comment: @Did, got it.  Well, if the measure space has finite measure (I know that no one said it did), then the problem reduces to the LLN.

Comment: @avs Not related at all.

Comment: @Did, I see the misconception I had.  Thanks.

Comment: be patient, I am someone who is learning.

Answer (score 1):

I´m have: $P(\{\omega: X_n(\omega) \to 0 \})=1$ Thus, simply show that: $P(\{\omega: \frac{1}{n}S_n(\omega) \to 0 \})=1$
therefore as:

$\frac{1}{n}S_n(\omega^{´}) \to 0 $,   for all $\omega^{´}\in \{\omega: X_n(\omega) \to 0 \}$ for the  Cesàro mean theorem

then

$P(\{\omega: \frac{1}{n}S_n(\omega) \to 0 \})=1$ thus $\frac{1}{n}S_n \to 0$ $a.s$

There is an error in my proof? carmichael561,  michalOut,  Byron Schmuland... thank you.

Comment: You mean Stolz–Cesàro theorem?